# Count if SSRS in textbox

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a scenario where I need to calculate a percentage based on 
- No of records with a certain value/ Total no of records. 
This is going into a textbox in the header. I am trying the following but I keep getting an error saying "Argument not specified for parameter FalsePart of Pulbic Function Iif.

Can anybody shed some light on this please?

```
=Count((Iif((Fields!Confirmed.Value, "KPI_Calculation")= True,1,Nothing)),"KPI_Calculation")
/Count(Fields!Confirmed.Value, "KPI_Calculation")
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your code does not work. Are you are using this function on a scope named "KPI_Calculation"? If so you have to determine if to calculate based on some variable or FIRST|LAST|SUM|MAX.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me in a simple test:

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!ConfirmedValue.Value, 1, 0), "KPI_Calculation") / CountRows("KPI_Calculation")
```

It looks like in your above example you're declaring a Scope too many times and hence getting a syntax error.

Comment: Did you manage to get the above statement to run successfully?